# How can I exclude specific association records in a LINQ to SQL query?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

Assume I have the following data:

```
Parent
  > Child 1 (Alive = true)
  > Child 2 (Alive = true)
    > Grandchild 1 (Alive = false)
    > Grandchild 2 (Alive = true)
  > Child 3 (Alive = false)
    > Grandchild 3 (Alive = false)
```

And I want to write a query to select all the records where Alive is true, thereby excluding anything where Alive is false.  This is the syntax I'm trying to figure out:

```
from p
in this.People
where p.IsAlive && (p.Children.IsAlive)  && (p.Children.Children.IsAlive)
select p
```

I would like the result set to look like this:

```
Parent
  > Child 1 (Alive = true)
  > Child 2 (Alive = true)
    > Grandchild 2 (Alive = true)
```

Comment: What is supposed to happen if `Child 4 (Alive = false)` and `Grandchild 4 (alive = true)`? And are `Grandchild` objects **actually** children of `Child` objects?

Comment: Yes, they are actually children.  Imagine a People table with a ParentId column that is a FK to the same table.  So in your example, Grandchild 4 would be excluded because Child 4 is not alive.

Comment: Do they have a navigation property to `Parent`, or is it only the `Id`?

Comment: They do have a Parent property

Comment: Have you tried `where p.IsAlive && (p.Parent != null && p.Parent.IsAlive || p.Parent == null)`, then a `groupby p.Parent`?

Comment: I need the selection to go the other way, like my description: `where p.IsAlive && p.Children.IsAlive && p.Children.Children.IsAlive`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below way:
1)  Create table People with recursive relationship by ParentID column:

```
Table name : People
ID  Name        ParentID IsAlive
1   Parent1     Null       1
2   Child1      1          1
3   Child2      1          1
4   GrandChild1 3          1
5   GrandChild2 3          0
6   Child3      1          0
7   GrandChild3 6          0
```

2)  Execute query like below for Alive records:

```
from p
in this.People
where p.IsAlive 
select p
```

Please let me know , is this way works for you ?